# How to pre-specify a selection when executing a program on Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I want to automate the execution of certain scripts in Linux, however I am not aware of how I can pre-specify a response to a choice window. For example when executing:

```
setoolkit
```

I need to select some choices by inputting a number (1 to 8) is there a way I can pre-specify which number to press so that I don't need to manually select an option?
For example:

```
setoolkit $1
```

Any comment is helpful!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit `setoolkit` in order to handle the input from the inside?

Comment: Whether `setoolkit` allows you to pass in command-line arguments top specify the desired action is not a programming question (unless you are working on updating the program itself, in which case be _much_ more specific), and best interrogated from its documentation.